# When click on item in table, related data should get populated in the other table in thae same screen

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want data in another table when click on first table item on the same page.when doing inspect element data is getting set in the first controller but then flow breaks and no data gets populated.Data is not being compared and not being called in another controller and no data is being displayed.

controller1:

```
     $scope.selectSport=function (data) {
     sportsCategoryService.setSportData(data);
     }
```

controller2:

```
        $scope.populateTable = function (data) {
    $scope.sportItems = data;
    $timeout(function () {
        $("#example1").dataTable();
    }, 200)
};
 if (!sportsCategoryService.isSportSelected()) {
    $location.path('/sportsCategory');
}

 sportsCategoryService.getSubSportsData(function (subSportsData) {
    $scope.populateTable(subSportsData);
})
```

service:

```
        function  getSports(callback) {
        AuthenticationService.loadSportsCategory(function (response) {
            if (response.data.success === true) {
                localStorage.setItem("sportData", JSON.stringify(response.data));
                callback(true);
            }
        });
    }

    function isSportSelected() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportsData")) ? true : false;
    }

    function getSportsData() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportData"));
    }

    function getSportsId() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportsData"))._id;
    }

    function getSubSportsData(callback) {


        getSports(function (response) {
            if (response == true) {


                var sportsId = getSportsId();

                var Sports = getSportsData();


                for (var i = 0; i < Sports.sportsData.length; i++)
                    if (Sports.sportsData[i].sports === sportsCategoryId) {

                        localStorage.setItem("sportsData", JSON.stringify(SportsCategory.sportsData[i]));
                        callback(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportsData")).subSports ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportsData")).subSports : null);
                        break;
                    }
            }

        });
    }

    function setSportData(data) {
        localStorage.setItem("sportsData", JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function getSportData(data) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportedData"));
    }

    function setSportsData(data) {
        localStorage.setItem("sportData", JSON.stringify(data));
    }



    function updateSports(data, callback) {
            AuthenticationService.editSportsCategory(data, function (response) {
                if (response.data.success == true) {
                    setSportsData(data);
                    callback(true);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `flow breaks` ? From view which controller function did you call to populate data ?

Comment: I am calling "getSubSportsData()" to populate data. and flow braeks means when using break points it do not go to comparing of data and comes out.

Comment: For comparison `Sports.sportsData[i].sports === sportsCategoryId` where did `sportsCategoryId` come from ? Does `Sports.sportsData[i].sports` contain the id ? Also inside for loop put `console.log` then see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is broken indeed... You send data from controller 1 to service, but then you don't call anything from service, so everything stops there.

You must realize that this:

```
sportsCategoryService.getSubSportsData(function (subSportsData) {
    $scope.populateTable(subSportsData);
})
```

is called only once, when you're controller 2 is initialized. What you want is that the callback is called every time the data change, not just once. For that, you need to implement some sort of event listener in your service, that is the service must store the callback and call it when some change happens.

For example, in your service:

```
// first add a method to register listeners
var changeListeners = [];
function addChangeListener (callback) {
    changeListeners.push(callback);
}

// then call the listeners when change (event) happens:
function setSportData(data) {

    // ... your process

    // notify listeners
    changeListeners.forEach(function(callback) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

And, when initializing your controller 2, you would register your listener like this:

```
service.addChangeListener(function(subSportsData) {
    $scope.populateTable(subSportsData);
});
```